# Send POST request for REST api method call

Tags: xamarin.android

I have a problem with sending POST http request. It stops on `(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()` and after timeout throws timeout expired exception, but if i send the same request via GET all works fine.

Does any body know what it can be?

```
try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = "POST";

            if (content != null)
                request.GetRequestStream().Write(content, 0, content.Length);

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                return new Response(response);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException exception)
        {
            return new Response(exception);
        }
```

Comment: Please create an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed problem with this code:**

```
        using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            if (content != null)
            {
                requestStream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
            }

            requestStream.Close();

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                return new Response(response);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, this is due to the code on the server not exposing this method as a POST.  If the server doesn't explicitly set anyhting, it defaults to GET only.